# Compiling libJPEG with Alchemy (-swc)

Tags: gcc, compilation, swc, libjpeg, alchemy

I have tried for a few days to compile -swc with -ljpeg but have not had any luck. 
Here is what i have been doing. 
in my jpeg_sample_linker.c, it has two headers

```
#include "AS3.h"
#include <jpeglib.h> //or #include "jpeglib.h"
```

and the rest of the file is pretty much empty but compilable(because all i want to do is to compile the file with the headers first).

And my gcc command is:

```
alc-on
gcc -swc -ljpeg jpeg_sample_linker.c -o jpeg_sample_linker.swc 
alc-off
```

And, gcc keeps on saying it cannot locate libjpeg.h
i have also tried

```
alc-on
gcc -swc  -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -ljpeg jpeg_sample_linker.c -o jpeg_sample_linker.swc 
alc-off
```

It still reported the same error "error: jpeglib.h: No such file or directory".

May i know how i could fix this compilation error?

Billion thanks
G

Comment: Try to locate your jpeglib.h file... Maybe it's in a different path...

Comment: Hi Macmade, thanks.  -I/usr/local/include returns 'jpeglib.h'.  I am thinking whether the alc's gcc doesn't link up with /usr/local/include

Answer (score 0):

What a bummmer,

```
the compilation can be solved by editing gcc in /Library/alchemy-darwin-v0.5a/achacks
or
moving everything in /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include to 
to $ALCHEMY_HOME/usr/local/include and $ALCHEMY_HOME/usr/local/lib
```

!